# Cast web server object to other (identical) web server object

Tags: c#, casting, data-objects

I have two web services referenced in my project. One is called `EmailService` and the other `TicketService`.

Both have a property called `Email`. And I have to do the following in my code now:

```
var mail = new EmailService.Email();
mail.from = "something";
mail.to = "someone";
mail.subject = "subject";
mailService.Save(mail);

ticketService.Send(mail);
```

The problem is that the `TicketService.Send()` expects an `Email` object from the `TicketService` namespace. So it fails at that point.

Casting also won't work in this case:

```
ticketService.Send( (TicketService.Email)mail );
```

That gives me the error that it is unable to cast expression from `EmailService.Email` to `TicketService.Email`.

I know I can use something like AutoMapper and simply map it from one object to the other. But I rather don't add another dependency to the solution.

Maybe it's not even necessary to add something like AutoMapper, since both `Email` objects are identical. So perhaps there is an easy way to do this?

In any way, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot because you are not applying polymorfism here, cant you map  one objects properties to the other one by one? Sometimes in software development is fine to use "translator" methods in order to do this if you are going to require to do this multiple times.

Comment: Why not create a `TicketService.Email` instead of a `EmailService.Email` in your function?

Comment: @Jite Because then the `mailService.Save()` method will complain that it expects an `EmailService.Email`.

Answer (score 0):

Look, if you want to cast stuff to other stuff willy nilly or go duck-typing everywhere, then you are using the wrong language.  C# is a statically typed language (with a little dynamic mixed in now) and it will not let you cast any old type to any other type.

Automapper is a solution, but a bit of overkill, yes.  You can, however, do the same thing it would--create a method that will convert an instance of one to an instance of the other.  It will seriously take you less time than you spent writing this question.

Alternatively, if you can, refactor the code to use the same instance of an Email object.  But either way, seriously, just dooo eeet.

Comment: Yeh but the problem is, is that I don't know HOW to convert one instance to the other in a good way. I can of course think of some ways, like I could serialize the object, then deserialize it and at that moment cast it to any object i want. But I just want to know what a good approach is. No need to be so grumpy about it. --- Refactoring isn't an option since i just consume the service. I didn't create it.

Comment: @Vivendi: `thisGuy.PropertyA = thatGuy.PropertyA; thisGuy.PropertyB = ConvertToPropertyBBecauseSuckit(thatGuy.SomeOtherProperty);` It ain't magic.  You write code to convert one into the other.